# Install level on cordless drill

Tags: drill, level

I would like to add a level to my cordless drill.

I saw this and thought it would work if I added it to the back of my drill.

I thought I would position the drill in the right position and then glue the level to the back of the drill to where the bubble is centered.

Do you think it would work?

[image: Level]

Comment: that would definitely work ..... you would be able to return the drill to the same orientation as it  was  when you glued the level indicators onto it ....... use double-sided tape to quickly determine if the idea works as expected .... then use glue

Comment: you could also use this technique if you have to drill a bunch of holes at some specific angle .... just tilt the drill to the desired angle, glue the level indicator so that it shows level .... i'm sure you get my meaning

Comment: i would use poster putty to allow quick in the field re-adjustments.

Comment: Has the technology improved since then, we are now entering 2024. What do I buy to get spirit level onto my drill.

Answer (score 3):

As Jsotola  alluded to,

You would have to use a  Long drillbit and  Clamp it  in a vice  so that the drill bit is plum  and true on all sides.

Then chuck the drill on to the drill bit.

Then you could glue your bubble on so that it is indicating level.

Good luck to you.

Comment: That's an excellent idea. I have a 16 inch paddle type bit.

Answer (score 2):

I used a hot glue gun using the milky colored glue sticks.

[image]